# Pointers/Papers on subdivision of planar quadrilateral meshes (PQ-Mesh) in 3D?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, computational-geometry

I'm interested in the subdivision of planar quadrilateral meshes (PQ-Meshes). Meshes consisting only of planar quadrilaterals, like discrete Voss surfaces and alike. I've been searching the web
for any existing research/papers on the topic, but haven't been able to come up with anything?

If someone can provide some resources on this matter I would be more than happy. What approaches have been taken to subdivide PQ-Meshes while retaining planarity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one recent reference, which cites others that you can follow (or use Google Scholar on its title):

> Tim Hoffmann, "On local deformations of planar quad meshes,"  In K. Fukuda, J. V. D. Hoeven, M.  Joswig, & N. Takayama (Eds.), *Mathematical Software–ICMS 2010* (Vol. 6327, pp. 167-169). Springer Berlin Heidelberg. [doi:10.1007/978-3-642-15582-6_31](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-15582-6_31). [Zbl 1294.68141](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1294.68141)

But this gives me the opportunity to mention this (literally!) beautiful book, which includes substantive coverage of PQ meshes (with citations, of course):

> H. Pottmann, A. Asperl, M. Hofer and A. Kilian:  *Architectural Geometry*. Bentley Institute Press (2007), 724 pages, 2200 figures in color, ISBN 978-1-934493-04-5. Book link at [www.architecturalgeometry.at](http://www.architecturalgeometry.at/)

[image: AG]

Comment: I know the first one, and it's references therein, though they are sadly not very concerned with subdivision.

I've seen the second one mentioned before but had not had a chance to get my hands on it. Thanks!

Comment: Note: "2200 figures" is not a typo!

Comment: Ok, I guess no one else wants to chime in. Thank you Joseph!